# What C# types can be accessed from ASP .net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, types, inline-code

Let's say I have a class called ApplicationSettingsManager, and I have a String that needs referencing from Javascript on my ASP .net page, I have done the following:

```
<%=ApplicationSettingsManager.IdNumber %>
```

And it works fine. But what if I need to reference a `Dictionary<String,String>`? Or any other slightly more complex type? Is it possible? Do I need to use serialization somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to use serialization somehow?

Yes, it is recommended to use JSON serialization when passing complex types to javascript. For example you could use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(AnyComplexObjectYouLike) %>;
</script>
```

Example with a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } }) %>;
    alert(value.key1);
</script>
```

which will render as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"};
    alert(value.key1);
</script>
```

in the final markup.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So then what do I have in 'value'? And how can I treat it as a Dictionary of strings?

Comment: "The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found" - how do I go about importing this namespace?

Comment: @DanielMcNulty, that's why I always post links in my answer to the MSDN documentation of the class I am using - because there's information about which namespacve and assembly this class is declared in. In this case it is `<%@ Import Namespace=" System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>`

Answer (score 0):

I did this yesterday:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant a dictionary as in Dictionary< String, String >. For some reason it didn't show in my original post, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use namespaces that are not included by default, you have to import them à the start of your file. For exemple, for Dictionary, which is defined in the System.Collections.Generic namespace, you have to write:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
```